# Transform a json file into a pdf

Tags: python, json, pdf

I should transform a json file into pdf. I'm having trouble creating a table that allows me to make items that are too long wrap automatically and not overflow to the right side.
I paste an example of the json code that I should transform into pdf and then my implementation in python (which unfortunately returns a bad result)

json code:

```
"allIssues":[
      {
         "ruleId":"name",
         "description":"Description123",
         "help":"Description234",
         "impact":"critical",
         "selector":[
            "abc1234"
         ],
         "summary":"long text",
         "source":"long text2",
      },
      {
       ...
      },
            ]
```

My python implementation:

```
import json
from fpdf import FPDF
import pandas as pd

with open('input.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)    

pdf = FPDF()

pdf.add_page()

pdf.set_font('Arial', 'B', 16)

# Title
pdf.cell(0, 10, 'Inspection summary', 0, 1)

pdf.set_font('Arial', '', 12)

df = pd.DataFrame(data['allIssues'])


df = df[['ruleId', 'description', 'help', 'impact', 'selector', 'summary', 'source']]


col_width = pdf.w / 2.2
row_height = pdf.font_size * 2

   for issue in df.itertuples(index=False):

    data = [
        ['ruleId:', str(issue.ruleId)],
        ['description:', issue.description],
        ['help:', issue.help],
        ['impact:', issue.impact],
        ['selector:', issue.selector],
        ['summary:', issue.summary],
        ['source:', issue.source],
    ]

    # Draw table
    for row in data:
        pdf.multi_cell(col_width, row_height, str(row[0]), border=0)
        pdf.multi_cell(col_width, row_height, str(row[1]), border=0)
        pdf.ln(row_height)

    # Draw line between tables
    pdf.line(10, pdf.get_y(), pdf.w - 10, pdf.get_y())
    pdf.ln(row_height)

pdf.output('output.pdf', 'F')
```

This is a screenshot of the output:
[image: output]

This is what I'm trying to achive
[image: ref]

Can you give me a hand? is it feasible to create something nice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a lot of steps in your code. You could simply loop over the columns of your transposed df and export each of them to html. Append all html tables to a root html element and export with `pdfkit`:

```py
import json
import pandas as pd
import lxml.etree as et
import pdfkit

your_json = """{"url": "https://www.abc123.com", "extensionVersion": "4.51.0", "axeVersion": "4.6.3", "standard": "WCAG 2.1 AA", "testingStartDate": "2023-04-03T09:35:06.177Z", "testingEndDate": "2023-04-03T09:35:06.177Z", "bestPracticesEnabled": false, "issueSummary": {"critical": 2, "moderate": 0, "minor": 0, "serious": 0, "bestPractices": 0, "needsReview": 0}, "remainingTestingSummary": {"run": false}, "igtSummary": [], "failedRules": [{"name": "button-name", "count": 1, "mode": "automated"}, {"name": "select-name", "count": 1, "mode": "automated"}], "needsReview": [], "allIssues": [{"ruleId": "button-name", "description": "Ensures buttons have discernible text", "help": "Buttons must have discernible text", "helpUrl": "https://www.abc123.com", "impact": "critical", "needsReview": false, "isManual": false, "selector": [".livechat-button"], "summary": "Fix any of the following:\\n  Element does not have inner text that is visible to screen readers\\n  aria-label attribute does not exist or is empty\\n  aria-labelledby attribute does not exist, references elements that do not exist or references elements that are empty\\n  Element has no title attribute\\n  Element's default semantics were not overridden with role=\\"none\\" or role=\\"presentation\\"", "source": "<button class=\\"livechat-button items-center bg-black shadow-liveChat rounded-full text-white p-2 h-12 transition-all opacity-0 pointer-events-none w-sp-48 opacity-0 pointer-events-none\\">", "tags": ["cat.name-role-value", "wcag2a", "wcag412", "section508", "section508.22.a", "ACT"], "igt": "", "shareURL": "", "createdAt": "2023-04-03T09:35:06.177Z", "testUrl": "", "testPageTitle": "ABC123", "foundBy": "ab@bc.com", "axeVersion": "4.6.3"}, {"ruleId": "select-name", "description": "Ensures select element has an accessible name", "help": "Select element must have an accessible name", "helpUrl": "https://www.abc123.com", "impact": "critical", "needsReview": false, "isManual": false, "selector": ["#plp__sortSelected"], "summary": "Fix any of the following:\\n  Form element does not have an implicit (wrapped) <label>\\n  Form element does not have an explicit <label>\\n  aria-label attribute does not exist or is empty\\n  aria-labelledby attribute does not exist, references elements that do not exist or references elements that are empty\\n  Element has no title attribute\\n  Element's default semantics were not overridden with role=\\"none\\" or role=\\"presentation\\"", "source": "<select class=\\"w-full absolute opacity-0 appearance-none text-value-small font-bold text-black uppercase cursor-pointer bg-transparent outline-0\\" id=\\"plp__sortSelected\\">", "tags": ["cat.forms", "wcag2a", "wcag412", "section508", "section508.22.n", "ACT"], "igt": "", "shareURL": "", "createdAt": "2023-04-03T09:35:06.177Z", "testUrl": "https://www.abc123.com", "testPageTitle": "ABC123", "foundBy": "ab@bc.com", "axeVersion": "4.6.3"}]}"""
data = json.loads(your_json)

## replace the above lines with the following in your case
# with open('your_file.json', 'r') as f:   
#     data = json.load(f)

html = et.Element("html")

# general info
html.append(et.fromstring(f"""<h3>Site link: <a href="{data['url']}">{data['url']}</a></h3>"""))
html.append(et.fromstring(f"""<h4>Date: {data['testingEndDate']}</h4>"""))
html.append(et.fromstring(f"""<h4>Summary:</h4>"""))

# summary table
summary = pd.Series(data['issueSummary'])
summary_table = et.fromstring(summary.to_frame().to_html(header=False))
summary_table.set('class', 'summary')
html.append(summary_table)

# issue tables
cols_of_interest = ['ruleId', 'description', 'help', 'impact', 'selector', 'summary', 'source']
df = pd.DataFrame(data['allIssues'])[cols_of_interest].T
for col in df.columns:
    table = et.fromstring(df[[col]].to_html(header=False))
    table.set('class', 'issue')
    html.append(table)
    html.append(et.fromstring('<br/>'))

pdfkit.from_string(et.tostring(html, encoding="unicode"), "./output.pdf", css='style.css')
```

With the following css file:

```css
/* style.css */
* {
    font-family: 'Liberation Sans';
}

table {
    margin: 20px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

table.summary {
    width: 50%;
}

table.issue{
    border: 0;
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
  }
  
table.issue td,
table.issue th {
    border: 0;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 5px;
}

table.issue tr {
border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
}
```

You'll get:

[image]

Edit: updated json with the data you provided + exporting additional data + improved css

Note: you will need to install [wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html) and make sure that it is in your path.

Edit2: limiting output to desired fields

Comment: Do you know if I also can include images on the html/pdf? I used this code: https://privatebin.net/?9e3a638b79a8c2e9#szTBEs6kMTiHvCHkSa1FRkZHjGf87ttk4CHqwX3v78P but didn't work

Comment: you have to specify kwarg `options={'enable-local-file-access': True}` (the value -here True- actually doesn't matter) in `pdfkit.from_string`. Also the path must be absolute: `img_path = os.path.abspath("image.png")`

Answer (score 0):

**disclaimer:** I am the author of `borb`, the library used in this answer.

Assuming your data looks like this:

```py
data = [
      {
         "ruleId":"name",
         "description":"Description123",
         "help":"Description234",
         "impact":"critical",
         "selector":[
            "abc1234"
         ],
         "summary":"long text",
         "source":"long text2",
      },
]
```

You can run the following code:

```py
from borb.pdf import Document, Page, PageLayout, SingleColumnLayout, Paragraph, HexColor, Table, TableUtil
from decimal import Decimal

# create empty document
doc: Document = Document()

# create empty page
page: Page = Page()
doc.add_page(page)

# use a PageLayout to be able to add things easily
layout: PageLayout = SingleColumnLayout(page)

# generate a Table for each issue
for i, issue in enumerate(data):

  # add a header (Paragraph)
  layout.add(Paragraph("Issue %d" % i, font_size=Decimal(20), font_color=HexColor("#B5F8FE")))

  # add a Table (using the convenient TableUtil class)
  table: Table = TableUtil.from_2d_array([["Rule ID", issue.get("ruleId", "N.A.")],
                                          ["Description", issue.get("description", "N.A.")],
                                          ["Help", issue.get("help", "N.A.")],
                                          ["Impact", issue.get("impact", "N.A.")],
                                          ["Selector", str(issue.get("selector", []))],
                                          ["Summary", issue.get("summary", "N.A.")],
                                          ["Source", issue.get("source", "N.A.")],
                                          ], header_row=False, header_col=True, flexible_column_width=False)
  layout.add(table)

# store the PDF
with open("output.pdf", "wb") as fh:
  PDF.dumps(fh, doc)
```

This generates the following PDF:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunately the structure of my json file is more complex, I'll leave you a link with an example.
In my pdf file I should first write the main data such as site links, the data in the issue summary, and the date. Next I should have a table for each element of "allIssues" (I don't know a priori how many elements it will have), with the structure you used in the code. Unfortunately I was not able to modify it so that it works. this is a json example: https://privatebin.net/?150a657dd0216682#ue92LCbNwgiZDQrYTyNrYHMt6w1H2QDvNsA7RYpetKi

Comment: @Zeld it seems that creating an HTML with styling css could meet your needs. Check my updated answer.

Comment: I understand that your JSON might be different from what you've provided in your post. You'll need to modify my code in order to make it work then. You could also make the code more generic and treat the JSON object like a dictionary, simply running over its key/value pairs and persisting them as is (or adding special handling in some cases). Either way, the general idea behind my answer will stay the same.